# Ionic nested state on back doesn't change state

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have parent state order, and child states tables and articles. On click event in 'table' ionic view it redirect me to 'articles' view. When i press hardware back button in 'article' view, url changes, but state is the same (order.article).
Here is my code

**app.js**

```
.state('order', {
    url: '/order',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/order/index.html'
  })
  .state('order.tables', {
    url: '/tables',
    views: {
      'order-tables': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/order/tables.html',
        controller: 'OrderCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
  .state('order.article', {
    url: '/article',
    views: {
      'order-article': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/order/article.html',
        controller: 'ArticleCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
```

**order/index.html**

```
<ion-nav-view name="order-tables"></ion-nav-view>
<ion-nav-view name="order-article"></ion-nav-view>
<ion-nav-view name="order-unpaid"></ion-nav-view>
<ion-nav-view name="order-undone"></ion-nav-view>
```

**order/tables.html**

```
<ion-view>
  <ion-content>
    <div class="bar bar-header bar-light" style="position: relative;">
      <h1 class="title">Nova porudzbina</h1>
    </div>
    <ion-list>
      <a ng-click="chooseItem(table.stoID)">
        <ion-item collection-repeat="table in tables">
          {{table.brojStola}}
        </ion-item>
      </a>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Also, when I put my ionic views into tabs, states changed on back button.

```
<ion-tabs>
    <ion-tab title="Tables" href="#/order/tables">
        <ion-nav-view name="order-tables"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>
    <ion-tab title="Articles" href="#/order/articles">
        <ion-nav-view name="order-articles"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

I don't need tabs, but I don't understand why in some case it works properly and in otner does not.

Answer (score 0):

In `ui-view` sense you are going to  'order.article' state from its parent: 'order' state and since your app 'order' state is 'abstract state', `ui-view`  fails silently and stay in the same state. however in case of `ion-tabs` your  ionic uses `ui-view` internally partially and it properly make and assign your tabs to 'order' parent (ignoring your abstract state). in that case when you transit to  'order.article'  its parent states become orders and thats why you can change to tabs by back button

Comment: I can't view page with abstract state. I understand that. 
`order.table` and `order.articles` are states that I am visiting. From `order.table` I go to state `order.articles` and from `order.articles` when I go to `order.tables` (on back button) I got exactly the same view ('articles') but url chandes to  `/#/order/tables`